# Rolsyn Can't get baseType

Tags: c#, roslyn

If you extend the class oneself created, you cannot get the base class description.
If direct extend Controller,you can get the base class description. 
Roslyn Version 2.9.0.
I upgraded Roslyn Version from 1.1.0 to 2.9.0.

```html
namespace BrnMall.Web.MallAdmin.Controllers
{
    class ModelOptionalRequiredPropertiesAnalyzer_R1 : BaseTest
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void Ac() {
        }
    }
}
```

```html
namespace BrnMall.Web.MallAdmin.Controllers
{
    class BaseTest : Controller 

    {

    }
}
```

```html
 var methodSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(methodDeclarationSyntax) as IMethodSymbol;
                    if (methodSymbol == null)
                        continue;
//Cannot get to base class
                    IEnumerable<ITypeSymbol> iTypes = methodSymbol.ContainingType.GetAllTypes();
```

```html
 public static IEnumerable<ITypeSymbol> GetAllTypes(this ITypeSymbol typeSymbol)
        {
            while (typeSymbol.BaseType != null)
            {
                yield return typeSymbol;
                typeSymbol = typeSymbol.BaseType;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do? What is it instead doing?

Comment: I need to parse the syntax tree of the code
Analyze the source code from the syntax tree。
But the syntax tree now parsed has no base class

Comment: Roslyn Version is 2.9.0
Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.8

Comment: Roslyn parsing ModelOptionalRequiredPropertiesAnalyzer_R1 class
There is no BaseTest in the syntax tree

Comment: Your question is unclear for a number of reasons.  Where does `methodDeclarationSyntax` come from?  Where is the `GetAllTypes()` method declared?  It appears not to be standard Roslyn method - is it an extension method or something?  Incidentally, from my own experimentation, `methodSymbol.ContainingType.BaseType` seems to quite happily return the base type regardless of whether you declared it yourself.

Comment: "MethodDeclarationSyntax" is the syntax tree corresponding to the source code
GetAllTypes() is added to the above code snippet,